# Show dynamically created divs one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show dynamically created li's one by one. Here is my code. Any idea why something like this would not work?

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var userInput = $('#inputNumber').val();
  console.log(outputResult);
  var modifiedResult = outputResult.map(function(item) {
    return '<li class="ball">' + item + '</li>'
  });
  $('.output').html(modifiedResult.join(""));
  $('.ball').each(function(i, e) {
    $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$('.output').html(modifiedResult.join(""));` the `li`s are already visible (`display` property is `block` by default).

It would suffice to add `style="display:none"` in the *html* strings you create with `#map()` function - see a demo below:

```js
var userInput = $('#inputNumber').val();
var outputResult = [1,2,3,4,5];
var modifiedResult = outputResult.map(function(item) {
  return '<li style="display:none" class="ball">' + item + '</li>'
});
$('.output').html(modifiedResult.join(""));
$('.ball').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `fadeIn` after created user `display:none` initially.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var userInput = 5;
  var outputResult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  console.log(outputResult);
  var modifiedResult = outputResult.map(function(item) {
    return '<li style="display:none" class="ball">' + item + '</li>'
  });
  $('.output').html(modifiedResult.join(""));
  $('.ball').each(function(i, e) {
    debugger;
    $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="output"></ul>

<input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
```